# What is AC Trig?

Tags: power-supply, oscilloscope

I have taken a look at the power supply board of my digital oscilloscope. I happened to find a pair of SMD pads where a capacitor has either been torn off or possibly desoldered.

The capacitor used to connect one pin of a PCB connector to ground. It is labeled "AC Trig" in the descriptive layer of the PCB (and of course Cxx in the placement layer). The connector trace is otherwise undamaged, i.e. whatever the connector pin is fed by on the power supply, is still connected. The flat ribbon cable from the power supply plugs to the main board of the scope.

Does anyone know whether "AC Trig" (I suppose AC trigger) has some fixed meaning for digital oscilloscopes, and if yes what? I don't remember that I have ever read something about it in the manual of the scope.

I am asking myself if I should "repair" the missing capacitor, or if the chinese who soldered the board together have purposefully removed the capacitor as part of some debugging... But if I don't know what the pin does, it is difficult to tell whether a "repair" improves or deteriorates anything.

Update: I am sorry, I did not read carefully enough. The manual says with respect to the trigger source:

> AC Line: AC power can be used to display signals related to the power line
> frequency, such as lighting equipment and power supply devices. The oscilloscope
> gets triggered on its power cord, so you do not have to input an AC trigger signal.
> When AC Line is selected as trigger source, the oscilloscope automatically set
> coupling to DC, set trigger level to 0V

Anyways, I am not sure if the capacitor is essential or if it might work without.

Comment: Is there a reason why you decided to open up the oscilloscope and make an investigation i.e. what is your motivation for looking at the power supply board in the first place? Is the scope faulty for instance? Have you ever noticed that in certain automobile models, some dashboard features (buttons/lamps etc.) are blanked out?

Comment: I replaced a damaged power switch (which I broke upon opening the case) and after soldering the new one in, I checked with a lens if there were some solder pearls left on the board. Thereby I found the missing capacitor.

Comment: It is better to have something and unpopulate it, than need it and not have it.  Open up and piece of equipment and there will be unpopulated components.  Different versions, features, options or testing.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: that was my suspicion too. There are several "missing" components on the board, but they look completely untouched. Only the specific pads I have mentioned look like there has once been something on it. Looks like a capacitor could be useful to eliminate some high frequency content above the Line AC signal, and so get better trigger signal. I just can't find a reason to remove it...

Comment: Have you ever found some feature that could be related to AC triggering to not work properly? If not, it's likely that capacitor is at least unnecessary, and possibly actively detrimental if included. The latter is unlikely if the proper capacitor is used, but a capacitor of the wrong capacitance or insufficient voltage rating could break things. It would be hard if not impossible to determine what the correct capacitance would be, though it may be possible to determine a reasonable VR.

Comment: @Hearth: to be honest I have never used that feature and probably never will. The traces and components in series (five resistors, an optocoupler) are all okay, so I can't think how the capacitor would ever explode first. The only thing is the cap is close to the edge of the board, so I could well have torn it off while disassembling. But I think I will just leave it as it is, and possibly live with a lacking feature I wouldn't have missed.

Comment: So test it.  Hook up to something at line frequency.  Activate line frequency triggering and scope should trigger at line frequency.

Comment: @oliver I would say, if 1) you don't know if it's broken and 2) you're unlikely to ever need it to work, leave it as is. It's more likely to be intentional than not.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: now I tested it. It was a bit difficult because I connected to a 18V 50Hz transformer, which made of course no difference if the signal was triggered by itself, or by the 50Hz from the scope. Then I generated a 50.1 Hz signal on the PC, and then I saw the a drifting of period 10 s when I switched to AC Trig, which was not there for channel1 trigger. So obviously, it is working (without the capacitor), but I haven't got a use case for that at all. Possibly very dirty mains signal which can't be triggered by itself or something?

Comment: Anyways, thanks to everyone for the advice.

Comment: The use case is testing equipment at mains frequency.  No need to mess with trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am asking myself if I should "repair" the missing capacitor

It is likely that the capacitor wasn't there to begin with. Lots of PCBs leave room for additional compensation components or otherwise optional parts. It makes the design more flexible as external circumstances change, e.g. the parasitics of the input connector change, etc.

> the Chinese who soldered the board together have purposefully removed the capacitor as part of some debugging

We leave unpopulated spots on the PCB in Europe and the US too, just to let you know. It's not some "cheap Chinese stuff" problem . Sometimes such capacitors are populated during factory calibration/adjustment procedure. You're really assuming a whole lot in your thinking!

Comment: No need to get angry, I just wanted to point out that it's not a Rohde&Schwarz, indicating at the margin that I have seen some odd stuff in chinese products. But in general they are well worth the price. Might it be that you are sometimes assuming redundant things as well?

Comment: @oliver Some really high quality stuff gets made in China too. I think most of Keysight and Fluke's lineup is made in China these days. And no one's ever called a Fluke 87-V low-quality!

Comment: Absolutely true. And even the cheap stuff being directly marketed by the chinese  is sometimes *much* better than higher-priced products that western firms have outsourced to china. Almost everything electronics comes from china. But it's pretty annoying nowadays that so many people feel entitled to accuse you of discrimination if you dare to mention that some things in the world are less than optimal. And it's off-topic anyway.